# ¿Cómo agregar llave foránea en tabla ya existente en PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Tengo la tabla **Nacimientos** la cual tiene la tupla **anio_nacimiento**, pero quiero que ahora sus valores sean llave foránea ya que harán referencia a **clave_anio** que está en la tabla **Anios**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es una restricción de integridad. Si ya tienes ambas columnas en las tablas correspondientes, lo único que necesitas hacer es ejecutar el siguiente comando para restringir la llave foránea:

```
ALTER TABLE "Nacimientos" 
   ADD CONSTRAINT fk_anios
   FOREIGN KEY (anio_nacimiento) 
   REFERENCES "Anios"(clave_anio);
```

Donde `fk_anios` puede ser cualquier nombre con el que te quieras referir a esa restricción.

Puedes revisar la documentación que ofrece PostgreSQL sobre restricciones los diferentes tipos de restricciones [aquí](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK).

Answer (score 0):

Con SQL lo haces asi :

```
ALTER TABLE NACIMIENTOS
ADD FOREIGN KEY(ANIO_NACIMIENTO) REFERENCES ANIOS(CLAVE_ANIO)
```